# How to add dependencies to a custom_target() after the fact?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to have a top level target, we'll call it `sdk_extraction` that is tested/built every time, and had depends on a bunch of generated files that are basically copies or minor transformations of files in the tree.

I build up the list of files to export as a property string/list, then when it's all said and done take that list and iterate through it, creating `custom_commands` for each one and then adding a dependency between the output file and the `sdk_extraction` target.

```
function(finalize_sdk_export destination)
    file(REAL_PATH ${destination} destination )

    add_custom_target(sdk_target ALL
        COMMENT "Exporting SDK"
        )

    get_property(sdk_source GLOBAL PROPERTY SDK_SOURCE )
    string(REPLACE " " ";" sdk_source "${sdk_source}")
    foreach (item ${sdk_source})
        string(REPLACE ${destination} ${destination}/sdk target "${item}")
        add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT ${target}
            DEPENDS ${item}
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${item} ${target}
            VERBATIM
        )
        add_dependencies(sdk_target ${target})
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

This fails with an error:

```
CMake Error at <redacted>/build_scripts/CMakeLists.txt:209 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target
  "<redacted>/sdk/CMakeLists.txt"
  of target "sdk_target" does not exist.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  <redacted>/CMakeLists.txt:78 (finalize_sdk_export)
```

Does this not work?     I WAS able to do this:

```
function(finalize_sdk_export destination)
    file(REAL_PATH ${destination} destination )

    get_property(sdk_source GLOBAL PROPERTY SDK_SOURCE )
    string(REPLACE " " ";" sdk_source "${sdk_source}")
    foreach (item ${sdk_source})
        string(REPLACE ${destination} ${destination}/sdk target "${item}")
        add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT ${target}
            DEPENDS ${item}
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${item} ${target}
            VERBATIM
        )
        list(APPEND sdk_files ${target})
    endforeach()
    add_custom_target(sdk_target ALL
        COMMENT "Exporting SDK"
        DEPENDS ${sdk_files}
        )
endfunction()
```

Where I make all the `custom_command`s and keep a list of each ones output, then make the call to `add_custom_target()` with them all specified in the `DEPENDS` parameter.

This works for now, but I'm still just testing and I'm unsure it'll hold up if I end up having hundreds/thousands of files in the export.

So, how am I supposed to do this **correctly**?

(FYI, I gave up with the built in cmake install/export functionality because we really want to have control over the directory structure and look/feel of the CMake files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All **files**, from which a custom target depends, should be specified in the `DEPENDS` option for `add_custom_target()` call. There is no way to add dependencies from the *files* afterwards.

The command `add_dependencies` can add only dependencies between **targets**.

Unlike to `add_dependencies`, which may connect *targets* creates in *different directories*, all generated *files* in `DEPENDS` clause should be created by `add_custom_command` in the **same directory** only. That is, it is usually not
a problem to postpone creation of the *target* unless all dependent *files* are calculated.

Comment: So from this, to do this properly I should use `add_custom_target()` once per directory that depends on the files OUTPUT from all the `add_custom_command()`s in that directory, then use `add_dependencies()` to connect all of those directories to a top level target?

Comment: Yes, this is reasonable approach.

Comment: FWIW, I get a ton of "built target <blah>" messages.  Is there a way to suppress those?  I guess it's not a real issue with ninja generator (which seems to re-use the line as its outputting), but if I end up having a hundred or more directories and have make as the generator, it'll spew hundreds of lines of stuff every time it builds, even if nothing happens in those rules

Comment: Googling gives me global target [TARGET_MESSAGES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/TARGET_MESSAGES.html), which, as far as I undestand, may disable at least part of messages related to building targets. You may set this property via cache variable in the command line by passing `-DCMAKE_TARGET_MESSAGES=OFF` parameter to cmake

Comment: Yes, that made a difference.   Thanks!  (of course, now there's a smaller subset of "consolidating dependencies..." calls, but not associated with this particular effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this by using generator expressions and defining a property for your custom target:

```
define_property(TARGET
    PROPERTY "SDK_EXTRACT_GENERATED"
)

add_custom_target(
    sdk_target ALL
    DEPENDS $<TARGET_PROPERTY:sdk_extraction,SDK_EXTRACT_GENERATED>
)
```

Then, to add your generated files:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT sdk_extraction
    DEPENDS ${item}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${item} sdk_extraction
    VERBATIM
)
set_property(TARGET ${target}
    APPEND PROPERTY SDK_EXTRACT_GENERATED ${item}
)
```

This works since [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) are evaluated during the build generation step, which runs after the configuration step.

This means that, since the SDK_EXTRACT_GENERATED property is populated at configure time, the generator expression will expand to the full list of files once the generation step is run.

Note that this is for file level dependencies, and target level dependencies should be added via the usual `add_dependencies()` call.